# Is there a way to get audio from an opencv webcam capture?

Tags: python, opencv, pyaudio, audio-processing

I am trying to do some audio processing in python, but I need both the video and audio as I wish to output both when I am done. I have looked up other examples, but they all use video files instead of live capture.

I have tried using pyaudio and MediaPlayer by passing in either the webcam or the cv2 video capture but no luck so far as they seem to expect a file only and don't take the opencv stream.

Answer (score 0):

The Audio and Video part are separate. Your Video stream does not have any Audio. You need to use the microphone "device" from the webcam and not the video stream.